# How can I make an interface implement another interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I have a interface which currently looks like this. But I want it to also implement IDisposable

```
public interface IFoo<out TOut>() where TOut : class, new()
{
}
```

I would like to say something like

```
public interface IFoo<out TOut>() : IDisposable : where TOut : class, new()
{
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: that is perfectly fine, do you mean to constrain `TOut`?

Comment: Patrick answered it for me. It would appear like I made a typo but I actually didn't know I had to drop the extra colon after the IDisposable

Comment: Aye copied from another stack question which had the class parenthesis included. But I hadn't a clue about the format of the ':'. I'll mark it as an answer once it will allow me. (7 minutes remaining)

Comment: I don't know why it was put on hold.. It can still be reproduced.

Comment: @LivingOnACloud: The ones voting thought it was a 'simple typographical error'.

Comment: Little did they know it was a gem of code behind a façade of typographical junkets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had a few mistakes in your code that didn't make it compile:

```
public interface IFoo<out TOut> where TOut : class, new()
{
}

public interface IFoo2<out TOut> : IDisposable where TOut : class, new()
{
}
```

1. Names were colliding.
2. You had a incorrect use of `IDisposable : where`. The `:` should be removed.
3. You have parenthesis like it's a method. You don't need them.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a full explaining working post.

Comment: 1. isn't correct is it? "I would like to say something like" doesn't mean that I want the two examples to exist at the same time. Or maybe I worded it confusing.
3. I fixed that in an edit. It was just a typo. 
So really the answer is 2

Comment: @LivingOnACloud: It didn't look like two attempts to be, sorry.